# How does the VPN server redirect all passed HTTPS requests to a fixed interface

Tags: proxy, centos, vpn, charles-proxy

Background: I installed VPN on CentOS (ipsec-vpn project on github). I want to direct all HTTPS requests that have passed VPN to a fixed interface. The function is similar to the Charles rewrite function. One possible solution is to build a server with Charles installed, set the VPN server agent to charles, and then use Charles to modify the request. But Charles can only be installed on the win server, and it's expensive to have another server. My question is:

1. Can VPN itself To achieve the above objectives?
2. If VPN itself can ,what should be done?
3. If proxies must be used, do CentOS have similar tools? How to operate?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem through DNS Sever.